# how to check the current time is the between opeing and closing time in case of shop

Tags: php, mysql

i want to find the logic if if the current time lie with in this range of time then my shop is open otherwise it is close 
i am able figure out the solution but logic is not correct when i consider the minutes 
only hour logic is

```
$time= "11:00 22:30"; //time interval
$var=explode(" ",$time);
$currenttime=date("22:00");  // currenttime
$opentime =$var[0];
$closetime=$var[1];

if($opentime - $currenttime < 0  && $currenttime - $closetime < 0 )    
{
  echo "open";
}
else
{
 echo "close";
}
```

this code work fine when i take the current time as 10 ,24 , 9 but when i consider as 22.30 or 11.30 not giving the correct result please suggest me correct solution for this .. thanks in advance

Comment: What do you think `date("22:0")` is good for?

Comment: current time for which we need to check

Comment: Yeah, but... `date("22:00")` returns... `"22:00"`... which is... pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Unix timestamps.The scetch below should point you in the right direction.

```
$unixStart = mktime(11, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j'));
$unixEnd = mktime(22, 30, 0, date('n'), date('j'));

$unixNow = time();
if (($unixNow >= $unixStart) && ($unixNow <= $unixEnd))
{
    echo "open";
}
else
{
    echo "closed";
}
```

Please ensure you call "date_default_timezone_set" and/or use DateTime/DateTimeZone classes to get the correct timezone.
The example below uses "America/Chicago", set your desired timezone instead

```
$objDTZ = timezone_open("America/Chicago");
$objDate = new DateTime('now');
$unixNow=time();
$objDate->setTimestamp($unixNow);
$objDate->setTimezone($objDTZ);
```

then

```
$unixStart = mktime(11,0,0,$objDate->format('n'),$objDate->format('j'));
$unixEnd = mktime(22,30,0,$objDate->format('n'),$objDate->format('j'));
```

Thank you,
Tom

Comment: Mockrat dekuje, Pane Martin!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like the explosion of the string is a bit unnecessary here.
This is a solution.

```
<?php

$openingTime = '1100';
$closingTime = '2230';
$currentTime = date("Hi");  // Current time

if($currentTime < $openingTime || $currentTime > $closingTime) {
    echo 'Shop is closed.';
} else {
    echo 'Shop is open.';
}
```

Also, don't forget to set the default using `date_default_timezone_set()`.
Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).

Answer (score 0):

Lovely one-liner ;-)

```
echo (date("Hi") > 1100 && date("Hi") < 2230) ? 'Open' : 'Closed';
```

Comment: $opentime  = strtotime("11:00");
$closetime = strtotime("22:00");
$currenttime = strtotime(date("H:i"));
if ($opentime - $currenttime < 0 && $currenttime - $closetime < 0)
{ $shop="open";} 
else 
{ $shop="close"; }                                           this solution works for me thanks for support